# Data in a given schema got truncated 4 times after every new build of the database

Tags: postgresql, psql, datagrip

I have a database with two schemas. The first schema was built weeks ago and have been stable ever since. The second schema under the same database in the same server is populated through an ETL process of the original schema. I built the data twice (approx 20 hours to build). I can see the schema takes the 100GB it requires from the hard drive. Upon connecting to pgadmin4 or datagrip, I can see instantly the data gets truncated (deleted) freeing up the space it takes. After the second build before connecting to anything, I made a File System Level Backup (tar file).
The first backup (3rd trial to keep the schema alive) I uncompressed the tar file and moved it to position keeping the uncompressed version of the folder in place.
I connected to pgadmin4 and the data disappeared again. Then I edited the postgres configuration data directory to point at the folder where I initially uncompressed the tar file to avoid copying and pasting in 2 hours. Launched postgres server again and boom, the schema truncates the data again.

I have no clue how or why this happens. Any advice on where to look next time before relaunching the server to pinpoint where that truncate command is fired from?

PS:
The tar file is a compression of "main" folder inside .../postgresql/11/ folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the information you provide we can only guess. My guess is that the transaction that inserts the data (`COPY`?) gets rolled back. This leaves the data added up to the rollback in the table, but as "dead" rows. Check fir errors in the ETL process.